# What are the reasons to execute a WebService from SQL?

Tags: web-services, sql-server

I was looking at some examples on how to call a Web Service from SQL Server.
And all of them show very unreadable code, that I imagine would be a nightmare to maintain. 
So, the main question is why to choose that approach vs a standalone program that can do the same.

Just for example one of the how to call a web service from T-SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE[dbo].[cm_genericHTTPRequest] 
{
@URI varchar(2000) = '',
@methodName varchar(50) = '',
@requestBody varchar(max) = '',
@SoapAction varchar(255),
@UserName nvarchar(100), -- Domain\UserName or UserName
@Password nvarchar(100),
@responseText varchar(8000) output
)
as

begin
--print 'starting the generic call'
IF @methodName = ''
BEGIN
select FailPoint = 'Method Name must be set'
return
END
set @responseText = 'FAILED'

DECLARE @objectID int
DECLARE @hResult int
DECLARE @source varchar(255), @desc varchar(255)

--print 'Creating MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP'

EXEC @hResult = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @objectID OUT
IF @hResult &lt;&gt; 0
BEGIN
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
SELECT hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult),
source = @source,
description = @desc,
FailPoint = 'Create failed',
MedthodName = @methodName
goto destroy
return
END

--print 'open the destination URI with Specified method'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'open', null, @methodName, @URI, 'false'--, @UserName, @Password
IF @hResult &lt;&gt; 0
BEGIN
--print 'error openiNg the destination URI with Specified method'
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
SELECT hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult),
source = @source,
description = @desc,
FailPoint = 'Open failed',
MedthodName = @methodName
goto destroy
return
END

--print 'set request headers'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'
IF @hResult &lt;&gt; 0
BEGIN
-- print 'error setting request header'
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
SELECT hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult),
source = @source,
description = @desc,
FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed',
MedthodName = @methodName
goto destroy
return
END

---- set soap action
--print 'set soap action '
--EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'SOAPAction', @SoapAction
--IF @hResult &lt;&gt; 0
--BEGIN
-- print 'error setting soap action '
-- EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
-- SELECT hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult),
-- source = @source,
-- description = @desc,
-- FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed',
-- MedthodName = @methodName
-- goto destroy
-- return
--END

declare @len int
set @len = len(@requestBody)

--print 'send request body'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len
IF @hResult &lt;&gt; 0
BEGIN
--print 'sending request body failed'
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
SELECT hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult),
source = @source,
description = @desc,
FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed',
MedthodName = @methodName
goto destroy
return
END

--print 'send the request'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null, @requestBody
IF @hResult &lt;&gt; 0
BEGIN

EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
SELECT hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult),
source = @source,
description = @desc,
FailPoint = 'Send failed',
MedthodName = @methodName
--print 'error sending the request '
goto destroy
return
END
declare @statusText varchar(1000), @status varchar(1000)

--print 'Get status text'
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'StatusText', @statusText out
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'Status', @status out

-- select @status, @statusText, @methodName

exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'responseText', @responseText out
--print convert(varchar(10),@hresult)

IF @hResult &lt;&gt; 0
BEGIN

EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
--print 'error getting response text'
SELECT hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult),
source = @source,
description = @desc,
FailPoint = 'ResponseText failed',
MedthodName = @methodName
goto destroy
return
END

destroy:
exec sp_OADestroy @objectID
--print 'destroying'
```

Comment: Show us one of the examples.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Hmm... Well, I wouldn't do it personally, but I can see how it might have some appeal.  Consider that SQL Server [used to have the capability to be accessed directly using web services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mds/archive/2010/02/09/getting-started-with-the-web-services-api-in-sql-server-2008-r2-master-data-services.aspx) (maybe it still does), and you maybe can see why having the ability to access web services directly from SQL Server might be appealing (think: integration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't want this. I can see a few reasons why this might be desirable, running a web query to fetch data in a trigger might be a nice idea, or returning data from a web service in response to a select call when reading data.

But these are all flawed, mainly because they all block the state of the DB whilst they are running - if inserting data fetched from a web query, until it returns your data is in an intermediate state. If reading data, it would block your query connection until it completed.

Both are bad. So put it where its supposed to be - the middle tier server and fetch data from both web service and DB and combine the data together afterwards, like how normal people do it :)